# Definite integral involving hypergeometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

I would like to know if the following definite integral of the product of elementary hypergeometric functions is known in closed form

$$
\int_0^1\,_2F_1\left(-n,1+n;1;x^3\right) \left[3 \, _2F_1\left(1-n,2+n;1;x^3\right)-\, _2F_1\left(1-n,2+n;2;x^3\right)\right]\, x \, \mathrm{d}x,
$$

with $n\geq1$.

Comment: You can deconstruct the hypergeometric functions into their corresponding sums and try to solve the integral of the parts.

Comment: It may be useful to notice that $ _2F_1\left(-n,n+1;1;z\right)$ is a [Legendre polynomial](http://functions.wolfram.com/05.03.26.0001.01) while $ _2F_1\left(1-n,n+2;c;z\right)$ may be related to its ([derivative](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.5.i)).

Comment: I attempt both suggestions sometime ago, and none worked. Thank you for looking into it though.

Comment: In the end, I managed to do the integral using the series definition around $x=0$ of both hypergeometric functions on the right. The integral is then simple enough to compute, and the sum can be expressed in terms of a $_4F_3$ generalised hypergeometric function evaluated at $z=1$. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us denote the integral by $I_n$:
$$
I_n \equiv
\int_0^1\,_2F_1\left(-n,1+n;1;x^3\right) \left[3 \, _2F_1\left(1-n,2+n;1;x^3\right)-\, _2F_1\left(1-n,2+n;2;x^3\right)\right]\, x \, \mathrm{d}x\,.
$$
We first expand both hypergeometric functions on the right of the integral using the series representation around $x=0$. This yields

$$
I_n=\int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{3 j x^{3 j+1} \Gamma (j+1) \, _2F_1\left(-n,n+1;1;x^3\right) (1-n)_j (n+2)_j}{j! (1)_j (2)_j} \mathrm{d}x=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{3 j x^{3 j+1} \Gamma (j+1) \, _2F_1\left(-n,n+1;1;x^3\right) (1-n)_j (n+2)_j}{j! (1)_j (2)_j} \mathrm{d}x
$$

The resulting integral can then be expressed in terms of $_3 F_2$ generalised hypergeometric functions:

$$
I_n = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \frac{3 j \Gamma (j+1) (1-n)_j (n+2)_j \, _3F_2\left(j+\frac{2}{3},-n,n+1;1,j+\frac{5}{3};1\right)}{(3 j+2) j! (1)_j (2)_j}\,.
$$

Now one can use the Pfaff–Saalschütz Balanced Sum (see for instance https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.4) to express the $_3F_2$ at unit value in terms of more Pochhammer symbols. In particular, we get

$$
I_n = -\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{2}{3}\right) (1-n)_j \Gamma \left(-j+n+\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma (j+n+2)}{\Gamma \left(-j-\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma (j+1) \Gamma (j+2) \Gamma (n+2) \Gamma
   \left(j+n+\frac{5}{3}\right)}
$$

which one recognises as being related to a $_4 F_3$ generalised hypergeometric function evaluated at unit argument. After some simplifications, one finds

$$
I_n=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{5}{3}\right)} \, _4F_3\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{3},1-n,n+2;2,\frac{2}{3}-n,n+\frac{5}{3};1\right)\,.
$$